# Form serializeArray does not work

Tags: jquery, html, forms

```
<form name = "indexSummaryForm">
<table class = "rtmindex">                                                  
    <tr>
        <td class = "rtmcolumntwo">
            <select id = "intraDayFXRateType" name = "intraDayFXRateType" class = "rtmindexselect">
                <option id = "4" selected>SPOT</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td class = "rtmcolumnfour">
            <input id = "preMarketOpenInterval" name = "preMarketOpenInterval" class = "rtmindexcell" type = "text" value = "0" />
        </td>
        <td class = "rtmcolumnsix">
            <select id = "intraDayFXRateBehaviour" name = "intraDayFXRateBehaviour" class = "rtmindexselect">
                <option id = "1" selected>Spot Rate</option>
                <option id = "2">Prev. Day WMSpot</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
</form>
```

When I try to submit the form, alert( "test: " + $('#indexSummaryForm').serializeArray()); returns null. Please check and advise what is wrong in the code?

Comment: indexSummaryForm is a name in your html, not an id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code

`$('#indexSummaryForm').serializeArray())`

is asking for an object with the **ID**="indexSummaryForm", you don't have an ID attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a form with **id indexSummaryForm**

```
 $('[name=indexSummaryForm]') // Should work
```

Otherwise you can add the id to the form and use the `id selector`

Comment: glad to have helped :)